# ASP.NET Core application http client request to a web api

Tags: asp.net-core, http-headers, dotnet-httpclient, webapi, bearer-token

I have a running Web API and I try to get a bearer token back from it. Starting the request from Postman is working and I get the token back. Once doing from my application I always get an http 400 Bad Request error.

What am I missing here?

```
public async Task<string> GetToken(string userName, string passWord)
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "api/auth/login");

    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{ userName}:{ passWord}")));
    request.Headers.Host = "api.my-host.com";
    request.Headers.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            
    var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

    var authResult = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<AuthResult>(responseStream);

    return authResult == null ? "" : authResult.Access_Token;
}
```

As requested here's a screenshot of the Postman result:

[image: PostmanResult]

I created a HttpGet request and added the bearer token from Postman in the code and I receive data. Just the token request seems to have a problem.

And my controller:

```
namespace AmsAPI.Controller
{

    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/auth")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
    public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IAuthenticationManager _authenticationManager;

        public AuthenticationController(IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        {
            _authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        }

        [HttpPost("login"), AllowAnonymous]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesDefaultResponseType]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login([FromHeader] byte[] basic)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest();

            string Basic = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(basic);

            var splitBasic = Basic.Split(':');

            AuthCredentials credentials = new()
            {
                UserName = splitBasic[0],
                Password = splitBasic[1]
            };

            return await _authenticationManager.SignInCheck(credentials) ?
                Ok(new
                {
                    message = string.Format("User {0} successfully logged in.", credentials.UserName),
                    access_token = await _authenticationManager.CreateToken(),
                    token_type = "bearer",
                    expires_in = "3600"
                }) :
                Unauthorized();
        }

        [HttpGet("user")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesDefaultResponseType]
        public async Task<List<User>> GetUser() => await _authenticationManager.GetUser();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pls try to request the token by postman, and show us the result. We need to check the content of this http request ?

Comment: Share your full controller? Does you controller allow `annonymous` request? Token controller should allow annonymous request.

Comment: Then Postman wouldn't work either...
Controller has <code>annonymous</code> request

Comment: Could you add your full controller class with action still its not clear about the problem

Comment: This is the full controller. I don't know what you're looking for?
Postman receives the correct data from the controller, but the client always receives Bad Request error and I don't know why?

Comment: Put `[Authorize]` on `GetUser` action and put `AllowAnonymous` on the top of `global controller`

Comment: Same result and I don't understand why you think the problem is on the API side? 
For me it looks much more a problem from the client side.

Comment: I think problem is here `GetToken` Let me investigate first

Comment: Check the solution I hope it will resolve your problme.

Comment: Hello was the problem resolved?

Comment: No it wasn't, but I found the issue. Will send an answer later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that Postman is sending the Basic Authorization Header as Content of the Http request and not in the Header, but my Web App was implementing the Authorization correctly in the Header.
So in the WebApi it looks like

```
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/auth")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IAuthenticationManager _authenticationManager;

        public AuthenticationController(IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        {
            _authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        }

        [HttpPost("login"), AllowAnonymous]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesDefaultResponseType]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login()
        {
            //check if header has Authorization
            if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization")) return BadRequest();

            try
            {
                AuthenticationHeaderValue authenticationHeaderValue = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(Request.Headers["Authorization"]);

                if (authenticationHeaderValue == null) throw new Exception();

                var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(authenticationHeaderValue.Parameter ?? throw new Exception());

                string[] creds = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes).Split(':');

                AuthCredentials credentials = new()
                {
                    UserName = creds[0],
                    Password = creds[1]
                };

                return await _authenticationManager.SignInCheck(credentials) ?
                    Ok(new
                    {
                        message = string.Format("User {0} successfully logged in.", credentials.UserName),
                        access_token = await _authenticationManager.CreateToken(),
                        token_type = "bearer",
                        expires_in = "3600"
                    }) :
                    Unauthorized();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
    }
```

and my request like following:

```
 public async Task<string> GetToken(string userName, string passWord)
    {
        //set request
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "api/auth/login");
        //set Header
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
            "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{ userName}:{ passWord}")));
        //get response
        var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

        var authResult = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<AuthResult>(responseStream);

        var token = authResult.Access_Token;

        return authResult == null ? "Authorization failed!" : "Bearer token successfully created!";
    }
```

and the httpClient is outsourced into a Service

```
public static void ConfigureServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var url = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("amsApiUrl");
        var host = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("amsHostUrl");
        //set HttpClient
        services.AddHttpClient<IAmsAccountService, AmsAccountService>(c =>
        {
            c.BaseAddress = new Uri(url ?? "");
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = host;
            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            c.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        })
        .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
        {
            return new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
                {
                    return true;
                }
            };
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have successfully reproduce your issue.

> You are getting `400` because its searching for `SSL` credentials but
> by default we don't have certificate bind with our request and its not
> required. So to handle this `400` exception you have to use
> `HttpClientHandler` which will bypass certificate error. So you can
> try below way to get the token response successfully.

***`HTTP Request:`***

```cs
public async Task<string> GetToken()
        {

            var user = new UserCred();
            user.user_name = "admin";
            user.password = "123456";
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };

            var client = new HttpClient(handler);
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);

            var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var url = "http://localhost:21331/api/Authentication/login";
            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);

            string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            return result;
            
        }
```

***`Output:`***

[image]

> **`Note:`** You need to add below code snippet to resolve your issue. But I like to call `HTTP POST` request in above ways to make it little
> clean. You can continue with your code just adjust what I suggest.

```cs
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
        var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Hope above steps resolve your problem accordingly.